# How to type-hint a variable whose type is any subclass of a generic base class?

Tags: python-3.x, generics, mypy, type-hinting, abstract-base-class

I have two abstract base classes that are linked, and should be subclassed together. For the sake of a minimal example, let's say its some class `TobeProcessed`, and a another class `Processor` that performs some processing on instances of the `TobeProcessed` class. I made the `Processor` `Generic` with the type of the `TobeProcessed` class as type-argument.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


class TobeProcessed(ABC):
    pass


TobeProcessedType = TypeVar("TobeProcessedType", bound=TobeProcessed)


class Processor(ABC, Generic[TobeProcessedType]):
    @abstractmethod
    def process(self, to_be_processed: TobeProcessedType) -> None:
        pass
```

Now I have some concrete implementations of both classes:

```py
class TobeProcessedConcrete(TobeProcessed):
    pass


class ProcessorConcrete(Processor[TobeProcessedConcrete]):
    def process(self, to_be_processed: TobeProcessedConcrete) -> None:
        return None
```

Finally, I have a "wrapper" class which has an attribute `processor` which is an instance of any subclass of the `Processor` class.

```py
class WrapperClass:
    processor: Processor

    def __init__(self, processor: Processor) -> None:
        self.processor = processor


processor = ProcessorConcrete()
wrapper = WrapperClass(processor=processor)
```

If I check this with `mypy` with `--disallow-any-generics` (or `--strict`), I get two errors for `WrapperClass` because I omitted the type parameter for `Processor`, which makes sense. However, if I replace `Processor` with `Processor[TobeProcessed]`, I get an error for the line `wrapper = WrapperClass(processor=processor)`:

`Argument "processor" to "WrapperClass" has incompatible type "ProcessorConcrete"; expected "Processor[TobeProcessed]"`.

Is there a way to do this without errors, and without making `mypy` less strict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `Processor[TobeProcessedType]` instead.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


class TobeProcessed(ABC):
    pass


TobeProcessedType = TypeVar("TobeProcessedType", bound=TobeProcessed)


class Processor(ABC, Generic[TobeProcessedType]):
    @abstractmethod
    def process(self, to_be_processed: TobeProcessedType) -> None:
        pass


class TobeProcessedConcrete(TobeProcessed):
    pass


class ProcessorConcrete(Processor[TobeProcessedConcrete]):
    def process(self, to_be_processed: TobeProcessedConcrete) -> None:
        return None


class WrapperClass(Generic[TobeProcessedType]):
    processor: Processor[TobeProcessedType]

    def __init__(self, processor: Processor[TobeProcessedType]) -> None:
        self.processor = processor


processor = ProcessorConcrete()
wrapper = WrapperClass(processor=processor)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I actually tried using `TobeProcessedType` instead of `TobeProcessed` as type-arg for `WrapperClass.processor` but I neglected to make `WrapperClass` generic with `TobeProcessedType` as argument. That was what was missing.